# "no caps" not working in Sublime Text

Tags: macos, voice-dictation, sublimetext

On Mavericks I'm trying to use the "no caps" dictation command in Sublime text but the word always appears capitalized.  I tested the command in the Safari URL line and it does work there.  Is there a work around for this?